# Can't use CustomErrors without causing AJAX error responseText to be blank?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

While trying to debug an AJAX error I decided to turn OFF customErrors in my web.config. The result was the responseText from the error section had the detailed message I needed. So while customErrors was on, the responseText was blank.

Is there a way to prevent the responseText from being blank but still use customErrors in the web.config?

Closest similar post on the topic is [this link that says instead custom error filters might be the better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298466/can-i-return-custom-error-from-jsonresult-to-jquery-ajax-error-method)

Here is the simple code I had:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/errorpage.html" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/filenotfound.htm" />
</customErrors>
```

Then here is the error handling that didn't show a message until I turned off the customErrors:

```
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('error called');
            console.log('status = ' + status + ' error= ' + error);
            console.log('xhr.responseText = ' + xhr.responseText);
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps parsing the result first with JSON.parse would help (depends on what's returned)? [How to get "Data" field from xhr.responseText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24546483/how-to-get-data-field-from-xhr-responsetext)